# Trying to search a column in a listview and return the result

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, listview

I am searching my listview from a specified index and returning the first result(the index the item is on) of the word. It works good except I can only search the first column in the listview. How can I search only the second column?

```
Private Function FindLogic(ByVal LV As ListView, ByVal CIndex As Integer, ByVal SearchFor As String) As Integer
Dim idx As Integer
Dim It = From i In LV.Items Where i.index > CIndex And i.Text = SearchFor
If It.Count > 0 Then
    idx = It(0).Index
Else
    idx = -1
End If
Return idx
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. This solution allows you to choose a specified index to begin the search from and checks the column with and index of 1.(Which is usually your second column)

```
    Private Function FindLogic(ByVal LV As ListView, ByVal CIndex As Integer, ByVal SearchFor As String) As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim It = From i In LV.Items Where i.index > CIndex And i.SubItems(1).Text = SearchFor
    If It.Count > 0 Then
        idx = It(0).Index
    Else
        idx = -1
    End If
    Return idx
    End Function
```

You could also add another parameter into the function so you could choose a different column to check for the string, like this:

```
    Private Function FindLogic(ByVal LV As ListView, ByVal CIndex As Integer, ByVal Column As Integer, ByVal SearchFor As String) As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim It = From i In LV.Items Where i.index > CIndex And i.SubItems(Column).Text = SearchFor
    If It.Count > 0 Then
        idx = It(0).Index
    Else
        idx = -1
    End If
    Return idx
    End Function
```

To use this function, it would look like this:

```
     FindLogic(Listview1, 1, 1, "Dog")
```

You could also have it search from a selected item like this:

```
     FindLogic(Listview1, 1, LV.SelectedIndices(0), "Dog")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to access the ListViewItem's ListViewSubItems to get the other columns.  With the sub items, you'll be able to search the different columns by index rather than just searching the text.  You can simply use a loop within a loop to perform your search.  You could be explicit if you'd like since you know you want to search only the second column, but by using a loop within a loop, you can actually search any of the columns. Here's a sample:

```
Dim idx As Integer = -1
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.lvwData.Items
    If lvi.SubItems(1).Text = "TextToSearchFor" Then
        idx = lvi.Index
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I was actually trying to search from a specified index and search for the first instance and return it's index. So I could begin the search on say line 5 and return the first instances index of the specified word.

Comment: It looks like you figured it out anyway.  The key was accessing the SubItems and not the Text property of the ListViewItem.